# oracle apex login issues (ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created an Oracle cloud free always Autonomous Database.

When I'm logging into Oracle cloud apex, the following error is being raised:

> ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database. This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured.
>
> The connection pool named: |ocid1.tenancy.oc1..aaaaaaaatqnhiz7jytt44dhoe4g2c4pdkn5h45ujjxdmddt3dvm5sy5ad6tq-db201912301417|re| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: Same here. i have access to my database with slqDeveloper but i cannot have access to apex workspace? did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure, but - it looks like an issue I had the other day where Apex wasn't working properly. I could log in, but everything acted very strange.

Googling around, it turned out that previous similar problems were caused by some server being shut down, and problems persisted until someone (DBA?) started it up.

Or, you might have hit the *scheduled maintenance* where database was really shut down.

If I were you, I'd wait a little bit (e.g. until tomorrow morning) and try again. If it still doesn't work, contact Oracle.